# one class is not detecting the other class's object

Tags: c++

I have two classes `Node` and `Wire`. I am getting an error for the line `vector<Wire*> inputs;`

**`Node.h`**

```
#ifndef NODE_H_
#define NODE_H_
#include "wire.h"

class Node{
private:
    bool sorted;                
    TGate gateType;             
    string name;                
    vector<Wire*> inputs;       
    vector<Wire*> outputs;      
    int state;  
    }
#endif /* NODE_H_ */
```

**`Wire.h`**

```
#ifndef WIRE_H_
#define WIRE_H_
#include "Node.h"
class Node;

class Wire{
private:
    Node* input;
    Node* output;

public:
    Wire(Node* a, Node* b);
    //void setInput(Node* in);
    //void setOutput(Node* out);
    Node* getInput();
    Node* getOutput();

};
#endif /* WIRE_H_ */
```

**`wire.cpp`**

```
#include "wire.h"
#include"node.h"

class Node;

Wire::Wire(Node* a, Node* b)
{

}
```

**`node.cpp`**

```
Node::Node(TGate gT, string name)
{
    std::cout<<"\nNode created is: "<<name<<"\n";
}
```

**ERROR:** /src/node.h:29:9: error: ‘Wire’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: Circular include dependency. That can't work. Use forward declarations.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Thanks, but this problem came only after i add `wire.cpp`...before that it was working well....Although by following the Answer you suggested, the problem has gone...but could you please tell me why the problem came only after i add `wire.cpp` and not before that?

Comment: If it seemed to work before it is by chance. Probably the lack of include guards?

Comment: @juanchopanza: include guards were there...i just didn't paste them in the question at SO

Comment: Before you added `wire.cpp`, did you have any `.cpp` file?  Compilers do not in general compile `.h` files by themselves.  Also, `node.cpp` should have an `#include Node.h` so the compiler knows what a `Node` is when it compiles.

Comment: @DavidThornley: Yes, `node.cpp` was there. Except `wire.cpp`, everything was there

Comment: @DavidThornley: and actually `Class Node;` was also present in `wire.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the headers, replace

```
#include "Node.h"
```

with

```
class Node;
```

and the same for `wire`.

You have mutually including `#include`s, so `"wire.h"` has to include `"Node.h"` which has to include `"wire.h"`, which has to include....  You need to break this chain, and to do that you use forward declarations.

The compiler needs to know that `Node` and `Wire` are classes.  Since the `#include` files only refer to pointers to the other class, the compiler doesn't need to know the class layouts.  This removes the mutual dependency and means the compiler can read all the code.

You also should have include guards, to prevent your headers from being compiled twice and causing redefinitions.  Some compilers allow `#pragma once`, and all can handle something like

```
#ifndef MY_WIRE_H
#define MY_WIRE_H
...
#endif
```

One stylistic note:  you've got `Node` and `Wire`, but `"Node.h"` and `"wire.h"`.  It will be easier to keep track of your files if they're consistently capitalized.

Comment: actually Class Node; was already present in wire.h....now my problem got solved after i wrote `Class Wire` in `node.h`...but why do i need to write in both the files?